# Emacs go to the beginning of line, skipping indentation

Tags: emacs

I have a line of code in emacs:

```
<tab><tab>int i = 0;<cursor>
```

If I click Ctrl-a, it will move to the beginning of line:

```
<cursor><tab><tab>int i = 0;
```

But I want to create an elisp function, that will ignore any indentation at the beginning:

```
<tab><tab><cursor>int i = 0;
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> M-m runs the command back-to-indentation, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
>   function in `simple.el'.
>
> It is bound to M-m.
>
> (back-to-indentation)
>
> Move point to the first non-whitespace character on this line.

Answer (score 6):

```
(defun beginning-of-line++ ()
  (interactive)
  (if (bolp)
      (back-to-indentation)
    (beginning-of-line)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'beginning-of-line++)
```

Then, If you click C-a, the cursor will move to the beginning of line, then click C-a again, the cursor will go back to indentation. The successive  C-a will toggle replace the cursor between beginning of line and indentaion.